# Cannot build curl with openssl (MinGW)

Tags: curl, cmake, openssl, mingw32, msys

I am using msys(MinGW32) to compile curl with openssl. It giving me '__errno' errors.

I changes following parameters as suggested on a github issue:
from `OPENSSL_LIBS = -lcrypto -lssl`
to   `OPENSSL_LIBS = -lssl -lcrypto`

which reduced alot of other errors but stil I cannot compile it properly.

OpenSSL v1.1.1b was compiled successfully with MinGW32. Curl version is 7.65.0.
I am using following command to build it:
`mingw32-make mingw32-ssl`

```
Use --enable-stdcall-fixup to disable these warnings
Use --disable-stdcall-fixup to disable these fixups
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: warning: resolving _gethostbyname by linking to _gethostbyname@4
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: warning: resolving _setsockopt by linking to _setsockopt@20
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: warning: resolving _getsockname by linking to _getsockname@12
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: warning: resolving _socket by linking to _socket@12
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: warning: resolving _connect by linking to _connect@12
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: warning: resolving _bind by linking to _bind@12
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libssl.a(rec_layer_s3.o):rec_layer_s3.c:(.text+0x3bb): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libssl.a(rec_layer_s3.o):rec_layer_s3.c:(.text+0x705): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libssl.a(s3_lib.o):s3_lib.c:(.text+0x243a): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libssl.a(s3_lib.o):s3_lib.c:(.text+0x24e4): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libssl.a(s3_lib.o):s3_lib.c:(.text+0x2634): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libssl.a(ssl_cert.o):ssl_cert.c:(.text+0x1da1): more undefined references to `__errno' follow
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0xbc): undefined reference to `getnameinfo'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0xff): undefined reference to `gai_strerror'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0x241): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0xd9a): undefined reference to `getaddrinfo'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0xdb0): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0xeaa): undefined reference to `gai_strerror'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0xf1f): undefined reference to `freeaddrinfo'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0x1132): undefined reference to `getaddrinfo'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0x1148): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0x124a): undefined reference to `gai_strerror'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0x12bf): undefined reference to `freeaddrinfo'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0x93b): undefined reference to `freeaddrinfo'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x2b1): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x30c): undefined reference to `ioctl'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x321): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x671): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x734): undefined reference to `ioctl'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x751): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x851): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x130): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x1c2): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x277): more undefined references to `__errno' follow
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x644): undefined reference to `listen'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x691): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x721): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x7be): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x81e): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x8be): undefined reference to `accept'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x901): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(bss_conn.o):bss_conn.c:(.text+0x7d4): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(bss_conn.o):bss_conn.c:(.text+0x88f): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(bss_conn.o):bss_conn.c:(.text+0xa2c): undefined reference to `shutdown'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(bss_conn.o):bss_conn.c:(.text+0xb46): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(bss_conn.o):bss_conn.c:(.text+0xe55): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(bss_conn.o):bss_conn.c:(.text+0xfd3): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(bss_conn.o):bss_conn.c:(.text+0x10f6): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(bss_conn.o):bss_conn.c:(.text+0x1405): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(bss_conn.o):bss_conn.c:(.text+0x1583): more undefined references to `__errno' follow
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(conf_mod.o):conf_mod.c:(.text+0xe01): undefined reference to `__locale_ctype_ptr'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(conf_mod.o):conf_mod.c:(.text+0xe84): undefined reference to `__locale_ctype_ptr'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(eng_ctrl.o):eng_ctrl.c:(.text+0x206): undefined reference to `stpcpy'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(err.o):err.c:(.text+0x218): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(err.o):err.c:(.text+0x2cc): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(err.o):err.c:(.text+0x948): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(err.o):err.c:(.text+0x9bb): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(err.o):err.c:(.text+0xfc6): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(err.o):err.c:(.text+0x1039): more undefined references to `__errno' follow
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(mem_sec.o):mem_sec.c:(.text+0xb4b): undefined reference to `sysconf'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(mem_sec.o):mem_sec.c:(.text+0xb9c): undefined reference to `mmap'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(mem_sec.o):mem_sec.c:(.text+0xc36): undefined reference to `mlock'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(mem_sec.o):mem_sec.c:(.text+0xcbf): undefined reference to `munmap'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(mem_sec.o):mem_sec.c:(.text+0xea8): undefined reference to `munmap'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(o_dir.o):o_dir.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(o_dir.o):o_dir.c:(.text+0x9f): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(o_dir.o):o_dir.c:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(o_dir.o):o_dir.c:(.text+0xc1): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(o_dir.o):o_dir.c:(.text+0xd5): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(o_dir.o):o_dir.c:(.text+0x12a): more undefined references to `__errno' follow
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(o_str.o):o_str.c:(.text+0x5ab): undefined reference to `__xpg_strerror_r'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(o_time.o):o_time.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `gmtime_r'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_unix.o):rand_unix.c:(.text+0x1e2): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_unix.o):rand_unix.c:(.text+0x321): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_unix.o):rand_unix.c:(.text+0x32c): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_unix.o):rand_unix.c:(.text+0x4a6): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_unix.o):rand_unix.c:(.text+0x51f): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(randfile.o):randfile.c:(.text+0x193): more undefined references to `__errno' follow
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o):threads_pthread.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `pthread_atfork'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o):threads_pthread.c:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_init'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o):threads_pthread.c:(.text+0x9b): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_rdlock'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o):threads_pthread.c:(.text+0xbb): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_wrlock'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o):threads_pthread.c:(.text+0xdb): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_unlock'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o):threads_pthread.c:(.text+0x100): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_destroy'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o):threads_pthread.c:(.text+0x143): undefined reference to `pthread_once'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o):threads_pthread.c:(.text+0x173): undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o):threads_pthread.c:(.text+0x1b5): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o):threads_pthread.c:(.text+0x1dd): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o):threads_pthread.c:(.text+0x243): undefined reference to `pthread_once'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o):threads_pthread.c:(.text+0x19b): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o):threads_pthread.c:(.text+0x1f1): undefined reference to `pthread_self'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(threads_pthread.o):threads_pthread.c:(.text+0x201): undefined reference to `pthread_equal'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `__getreent'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `__getreent'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:(.text+0x123): undefined reference to `sigaction'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:(.text+0x268): undefined reference to `tcsetattr'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:(.text+0x355): undefined reference to `sigaction'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:(.text+0x424): undefined reference to `tcsetattr'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:(.text+0x658): undefined reference to `tcgetattr'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:(.text+0x671): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:(.text+0x67f): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:(.text+0x68d): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:(.text+0x69b): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:(.text+0x6a5): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:(.text+0x6af): more undefined references to `__errno' follow
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:(.text+0x741): undefined reference to `__getreent'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:(.text+0x753): undefined reference to `__getreent'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(uid.o):uid.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `getuid'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(uid.o):uid.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `geteuid'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(uid.o):uid.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `getgid'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(uid.o):uid.c:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `getegid'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o):cryptlib.c:(.text+0x335): undefined reference to `__getreent'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(eng_openssl.o):eng_openssl.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `__getreent'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(eng_openssl.o):eng_openssl.c:(.text+0x1ab): undefined reference to `__getreent'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(loader_file.o):loader_file.c:(.text+0xe21): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(loader_file.o):loader_file.c:(.text+0x1034): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(loader_file.o):loader_file.c:(.text+0x112f): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(loader_file.o):loader_file.c:(.text+0x1140): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(loader_file.o):loader_file.c:(.text+0x1c2a): undefined reference to `__errno'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a(loader_file.o):loader_file.c:(.text+0x1ca4): more undefined references to `__errno' follow
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.m32:369: recipe for target 'libcurl.dll' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [libcurl.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'c:/Users/John/Downloads/curl/curl-7.65.0/lib'
Makefile:61: recipe for target 'mingw32-ssl' failed
mingw32-make: *** [mingw32-ssl] Error
```

What should I do so that I can build curl with openssl successfully ?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted old compiled files. Started again.
Compiled Openssl v1.1.1b, then built curl v7.65.0 with Openssl v1.1.1b. It worked.